What does the phrase "me ficher à l'eau" mean?
I have come across a baffling expression, and it is "me ficher à l'eau."
I found it in a quote from Georges Feydeau’s play "Le Dindon." The quote (and my attempt at a translation) is as follows.

VATELIN. — Ah ! non, ce que ça me dit ! Ce que ça me dit !… autant que de me ficher à l'eau !
VATELIN. — Ah! no, what that tells me! What that tells me!… may as well thrust myself into the water!

When I Googled the expression, all I could find was this page on Wiktionary.
My translation of the definition that it lists is "detestable solution that one envisages in an extreme situation."
I must confess to being skeptical, because it is a verbal phrase, and the definition seems more appropriate for a noun, not a verbal phrase.
By the way, my Google search brought up the phrase "me jeter à l'eau," which literally means "to throw myself into the water," but figuratively means "to take the plunge" (i.e. to commit oneself to a course of action about which one is nervous). I wonder if there is some sort of connection between "me ficher à l'eau" and "me jeter à l'eau."

Not sure if there is more to this than dictionary look-up. Se ficher is simply the pronominal form of ficher, for which fr.wikt provides the meaning planter. More generally, ficher is synonymous with mettre in all acceptions, which include an euphemism for foutre. The detestable solution is itself euphemistic for "to commit suicide by drowning". Whence: VATELIN. - Ah! really, how about it! How about it!… How about {dropping dead | jumping from a bridge | jumping from a cliff}, rather!

In some context "se ficher/foutre à l'eau" means commit a suicide by jumping into the water. It  is synonyme of "se foutre en l'air" (top yourself*).

Google search is correct here and there is indeed a connection.
"Fiche" is a euphemism for "foutre" which is both a vulgar way to say "mettre" and a vulgar word for "cum".
Despite being euphemistic, "fiche" is still familiar.
It is also a strange verb grammatically speaking.
Here "se fiche à l'eau" is in turn a euphemism for "to commit suicide".
A translation for what Vatelin says could be:
"Hell no! Would I like that? About as much as throwing myself off a bridge."

Ah, is that what Vatelin is getting at? Well, I suppose it explains a lot.
